# update gnome in centos 6.4

Tags: linux, gnome

my current version of gnome is : 2.28.2 and I want to update it to version 3. is there a way to do that ? I searched a lot about this problem , but all of the results is about installing gnome on a minimal centos . Im using centos 6.4

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to run Gnome3 on CentOS? It seems like there might be a conflict of interests at play here. CentOS is an Enterprise platform which is quite often run without a Desktop Manager - especially one as large as Gnome3. If you're using CentOS on a server, you're probably better without Gnome3. If you're using it as a desktop and want to use the latest version of Gnome, you may be better served by a different distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Gnome 3 is not supported by RHEL or CentOS at this time. As such, it is not in any of the official repositories. Additionally, I don't believe that there is any RPM resource that will reliably install it on CentOS. The most reliable way for you to get it running *in your case* is to [compile it from source](https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell#Building).

It's notable that gnome.org provides useful information for dependancies across varying distributions. However, [the information for CentOS](https://wiki.gnome.org/JhbuildDependencies/CentOS) is *incomplete* (CentOS 6 is not even mentioned) and *most likely outdated*.

**For a bit of background information**: Part of the philosophy behind RedHat and, by association, CentOS is to prioritize stability and performance over convenience. They are arguably intended to be used without a GUI at all. This is primarily why Gnome 3 never gained official support for the server distributions, with its significantly higher resource requirements and focus on the UI.